# Magento - moving domain auto redirect to right url

Tags: magento, redirect

i have magento 1.6.2. Plesk 11 on  my linus Ubuntu 10.04 lts webserver (with root access)

My website is now on for e.g. on domain aaa.nl
We gonna rename the webshop and have a new domain for this. Like bbb.nl

A lot of sites have external links to our site ... like aaa.nl/shopby/boys.html

But when i set to redirect traffic from the old website to the new one (trough plesk 11) they are all redirected to bbb.nl (without the specific product or category)

How can i set magento up so when people now go to link aaa.nl/shopby/boys.html they automatically are redirected to bbb.nl/shopby/boys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it via `Plesk 11` do it via .htaccess. Inside your Magento's .htaccess add this code just below RewriteBase line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aaa\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://bbb.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```